# Перенос атрибутов на новую строку, vs code, vue, volar, max attributes per line

Tags: visual-studio-code, vue-cli, eslint, prettier

Создал дефолтное приложение Vue при помощи команды **vue create vue-project**. Установил Volar для форматирования vue компонентов. Столкнулся с проблемой, что форматировщик не переносит атрибуты в несколько строк (если один атрибут то в одной строке, если 2 или больше то каждый с новой).
Посмотрел настройки Volar такой опции не нашёл.
Тут даже не совсем понимаю на каком уровне это нужно менять, так чтобы это всегда работало. Настройки vs code, volar, es lint или prettier?

Comment: заголовок сделай нормальный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## "html.format.wrapAttributes"

Это настройки HTML, а не Vue [html.format.wrapAttributes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting)

#### Не установлено

```html
<div one="one" two="two" three="three">
  ...
</div>
```

#### "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force"

```html
<div one="one"
  two="two"
  three="three">
  ...
</div>
```

#### "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"

```html
<div one="one"
     two="two"
     three="three">
  ...
</div>
```

#### "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline"

```html
<div
  one="one"
  two="two"
  three="three"
>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Открыл настройки settings.json добавил эту строку "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force".
Возвращаюсь в компонент -> нажимаю ctrl + s -> форматирования не происходит.
Нажимаю прав клав. мыши -> форматировать документ -> тоже самое, всё на месте.
Нажимаю прав клав. мыши -> форматировать документ с помощью -> в списке стоит только Volar

Comment: Правда на **html** файле то точно должно работать. Сохраняю html - всё равно не происходит форматирование

Comment: Итак. Задача была решена след образом:
Почему-то у меня форматировщиком по умолчанию для HTML подставился некий **esbenp.prettier-vscode** при нажатии на форматирование ctrl+alt+f появилось окошко "Расширение  **esbenp.prettier-vscode** настроено в качестве форматировщика, но недоступно" - дальше предложило настроить -> выбрал по умолчанию и всё заработало.

Comment: @Ярослав Никогда не понять мне: как этим ~га(м)ном~ "Prettier", люди пользуются. Пытался пару раз его ставить и все время получалось "Ugly".